# c#: Firefox not showing the Scrollbar on a Listbox

Tags: c#, javascript, css, firefox

We are having a browser issue and wanted to see if some knows why this might be happening

we have a vintage site using asp list boxes as

```
<asp:listbox 
id="zip" runat="server" DataTextField="something" DataValueField="something" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="240px" rows="2" /></td>
```

on IE(7, 8, 9, 10) and Chrome the list box is displayed with the scrollbar But in Firefox the same is not getting displayed.

Any thoughts why?

Though when we change the rows to "3" instead of "2" the scroll bar is displayed.

Comment: [See my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20508116/1729885), applies verbatim to your problem.

Comment: While I agree that the answer is probably identical. that doesn't make this a duplicate question! Future visitors looking for a solution to a problem with `select` or `listbox` won't think to search for a question about textareas.

Comment: yeah think i got my answer."Firefox won't show scrollbars for 2 row textarea"